# object not found in localhost while using xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have created a virtualhost in the `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` which is following-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/current"
    ServerName gjtest.no
    <Directory "/var/www/current" >
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and added gjtest.no to `/etc/hosts` file like `127.0.0.1` `gjtest.no`

But whenever I tried the `gjtest.no` URL in the browser I get the following error

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>   If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30
>   mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3**

The url is automatically changed to localhost

Comment: Where's your `<VirtualHost>` tag? Did you reload the Apache configuration after making changes (eg by restarting Apache)?

Comment: Yes. I have restarted Apache.